# Django default information for model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have 2 models (the Timeline one which will contain default information that I have to upload, and the Pdf one that contains the file and a relation to one of the timeline cells). I was told to create my own migration file and have done the following but I get this error and I can't find anything online about it:

```
 File "/Users/fetz/Desktop/parentsuportal/parentsuportal/timeline/migrations/0005_auto_20200324_1721.py", line 33, in addData
    Timeline(header = "Transport Support", age = "18-25")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 520, in __hash__
    raise TypeError("Model instances without primary key value are unhashable")
TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable
```

My models:

```
HEADER_CHOICES = [
    ('Financial Support', 'Financial Support'),
    ('Educational Support', 'Educational Support'),
    ('Governmental Support', 'Governmental Support '),
    ('Charity Support Groups', 'Charity Support Groups'),
    ('Therapy Support', 'Therapy Support '),
    ('Transport Support', 'Transport Support ')
]
AGE_CHOICES = [
    ('0-4', '0-4'),
    ('4-11', '4-11'),
    ('11-18', '11-18'),
    ('18-25', '18-25')
]

class Timeline(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=HEADER_CHOICES)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=AGE_CHOICES)

class Pdf(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='timelinepdfs')
    timeline = models.ForeignKey(Timeline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My migration file:

```
from django.db import migrations

def addData(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Timeline = apps.get_model("timeline", "Timeline")
    timeline = {
        Timeline(header = "Financial Support", age = "0-4"),
        Timeline(header = "Financial Support", age = "4-11"),
        Timeline(header = "Financial Support", age = "11-18"),
        Timeline(header = "Financial Support", age = "18-25"),
        Timeline(header = "Educational Support", age = "0-4"),
        Timeline(header = "Educational Support", age = "4-11"),
        Timeline(header = "Educational Support", age = "11-18"),
        Timeline(header = "Educational Support", age = "18-25"),
        Timeline(header = "Governmental Support", age = "0-4"),
        Timeline(header = "Governmental Support", age = "4-11"),
        Timeline(header = "Governmental Support", age = "11-18"),
        Timeline(header = "Governmental Support", age = "18-25"),
        Timeline(header = "Charity Support Groups", age = "0-4"),
        Timeline(header = "Charity Support Groups", age = "4-11"),
        Timeline(header = "Charity Support Groups", age = "11-18"),
        Timeline(header = "Charity Support Groups", age = "18-25"),
        Timeline(header = "Therapy Support", age = "0-4"),
        Timeline(header = "Therapy Support", age = "4-11"),
        Timeline(header = "Therapy Support", age = "11-18"),
        Timeline(header = "Therapy Support", age = "18-25"),
        Timeline(header = "Transport Support", age = "0-4"),
        Timeline(header = "Transport Support", age = "4-11"),
        Timeline(header = "Transport Support", age = "11-18"),
        Timeline(header = "Transport Support", age = "18-25")
    }
    timeline.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('timeline', '0004_auto_20200323_1947'),
    ]

    operations = [
         migrations.RunPython(addData),
    ]
```

Comment: There are lots of SO google results for "TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable"

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax I tried googling but nothing I found helped me. That's why I posted my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the Timeline instance before using it in a set. This is because a set uses the `__hash__` method to identify the instance (so that the collection has unique items) and a Django Model class's `__hash__` method requires an pk. The solution is to use a different collection class, such as a list and iterate over it.

```
timelines = [
    Timeline(header = "Financial Support", age = "0-4"),
    Timeline(header = "Financial Support", age = "4-11"),
    ...
]
for timeline in timelines:
    timeline.save()
```

Or you could use:

```
Timeline.objects.create(header = "Financial Support", age = "0-4")
Timeline.objects.create(header = "Financial Support", age = "4-11")
...
```

Or if you're worried about them already existing:

```
Timeline.objects.get_or_create(header = "Financial Support", age = "0-4")
Timeline.objects.get_or_create(header = "Financial Support", age = "4-11")
...
```

Comment: Yes thanks the for loop worked. Thanks for the assistance